# How to say HEAD~20 if exists, else first commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have the alias:

```
git rebase --interactive --autostash --autosquash HEAD~20
```

This works great except when I'm working on a new repository with less than 20 commits, in which case I get the message:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream 'HEAD~20'
```

How can I say: `HEAD~20 or else the earliest commit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do (in bash) `$( git log -n 20 --pretty="%h" --first-parent | tail -n 1 )`. So, for example....

```
git checkout $( git log -n 20 --pretty="%h" --first-parent | tail -n 1 )
```

Adjust to your recipe.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about it. Let me adjust the recipe. Thanks, @PetSerAl

Answer (score 0):

Based on [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52741118/5353461), I came up with the following aliases:

```
# Print the $1-th first-parent of commit $2
# or the earliest existing commit if the beginning of history is reached
parent = !"[ \"${1:-1}\" -eq \"${1:-1}\" ] && c=$(git rev-parse \"${2:-@}\") && git log -n\"$(expr \"${1:-1}\" + 1)\" --first-parent --pretty=\"%H\" --reverse \"$c\" | head -n1 #"
```

It takes two optional arguments:

- `$1` - How many parents to go back. Defaults to `1`, or the immediate parent
- `$2` - The commit-ish to operate on, defaulting to `HEAD`

If the 0th parent is requested, the commit itself (or HEAD) is returned.

This is used inside my `rebase --interactive` alias:

```
rbi = !"git rebase --interactive --autostash --autosquash --root \"$(git rev-parse \"${1:-$(git parent 50)}\")\" #"
```